# Redirection after x seconds in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Hope you're all fine.
I'm adding something into my database, when I press submit, I'm going to another page with an bootstrap alert which says that my Article has been added. What I want here, is that after x seconds, I'll be redirected to another page.

I only find some php code like `header("Refresh:0; url=page2.php");`
There is no Laravel php for that ?

Cordially

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm going to another page with an bootstrap alert which says that my
> Article has been added

It only can be done by JS using `window.location.href` after `setTimeout`

for example

```
@if (session()->has('message'))
    <script>
       setTimeout(function() {
           window.location.href = "YOUR URL"
       }, 2000); // 2 second
    </script>
@endif
```